# Material UI Select component not picking input value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have implemented a Material UI Select component that houses categories from which a user picks. The problem I have is that the category value is not getting picked and as such I get the following Django backend error

IntegrityError at /api/courses/, null value in column "category_id" violates not-null constraint

What could I be doing wrong? Here are the files I am working with.

NewCourseView.js

```
const newCourse = ({  
  allcategory,
  category,
  handleSelectChange,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="upload-course-form">
          <Typography className="form-titltle" variant="h6" gutterBottom>
            CREATE COURSE
          </Typography>

            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel
                htmlFor="select-category"
              >
                Category
              </InputLabel>
              <Select
                name="category"
                value={category}
                onChange={handleSelectChange}
                className="select-categories"
                inputProps={{
                  id: "select-category",
                }}
              >
                {" "}
                {allcategory.map(cate => (
                  <MenuItem key={cate.id} value={cate.id}>
                    {cate.title}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>


            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <button onClick={handleSubmit} className="submit-course-button">
                {" "}
                SUBMIT
              </button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    </div>
  );
};

newCourse.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
  handleSelectChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  allcategory: PropTypes.array,
  category: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

export default newCourse;
```

NewCourseContainer

```
export class CreateCourse extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      category: "",
      allcategory: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.categories();
  }

  handleSelectChange = e => {
    this.setState({ category: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      video: {
        category: this.state.category,
      }
    };
    this.props.dispatch(createNewCourseAction(data));
  };

  categories = () => {
    let initial = [];
    fetch(API_URLS.FETCH_CATEGORIES, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: myHeaders
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        initial = data.categorys.results.map(category => {
          return category;
        });
        this.setState({
          allcategory: initial
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        toast.error(error, { autoClose: 3500, hideProgressBar: true });
      });
  };


  render() {

    const {
      category,
      allcategory
    } = this.state;


      return (
          <div>
            <NewCourse
              handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              category={category}
              allcategory={allcategory}
              handleSelectChange={this.handleSelectChange}
            />
          </div>
      );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ dispatch });

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CreateCourse);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In selector:

```
onChange={(e, k, val) => this.handleSelectChange(e, k, val)}
```

handleSelectChange:

```
handleSelectChange = (e, k, val) => {
    this.setState({ category: val });
};
```

Comment: I tried that solution but now I get this error `Failed prop type: The prop value is marked as required in ForwardRef(SelectInput), but its value is undefined.`

Comment: Try to add:

<Select
                name="category"
                value={category && category}
                onChange={(e, k, val) => this.handleSelectChange(e, k, val)}
                className="select-categories"
                inputProps={{
                  id: "select-category",
                }}
              >
                {" "}
                {allcategory && allcategory.map(cate => (
                  <MenuItem key={cate.id} value={cate.id}>
                    {cate.title}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>

Comment: If the code above does not help, try to remove temporary isRequired from PropdTypes.

Comment: category value is still undefined but when I change the handleSelectChnage function to handleSelectChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ category: e.target.value});
}; ,  the undefined error message disappears and I remain with the original problem

Comment: Put console.log before render method and see what is present in the  allcategory,
  category:
const newCourse = ({  
  allcategory,
  category,
  handleSelectChange,
}) => {
console.log('category: ' + JSON.stringify(category));
console.log('allcategory: ' + JSON.stringify(allcategory));
  return (...

Comment: Thanks, I have done that and here is the result of the console.
`allcategory: [{"id":1,"title":"general","slug":"general"},{"id":2,"title":"Music","slug":"music"},{"id":3,"title":"Photography","slug":"photography"},{"id":4,"title":"Programming","slug":"programming"}]`

Category is an Id of any object in the array that I choose. I chose music and here is the result 
`category: 2`

Comment: All looks OK. In my project the similar problem was in the code that I wrote above. I've tried to help you with problem solving and detecting.

Comment: Thanks for lending a hand. I am gonna keep debugging, will let you know once I have fixed the problem.